# SharePoint 2013 for storage of Large Lists / Document Libraries?

Tags: list, document-library, list-view, limitations, threshold

We're currently facing a concern about the potential size of our Lists / Document Libraries which may well reach up to a Million.

I read that a single List / Document Library can store up to 30,000,000 items but has a List View threshold of 5,000, which essentially forces you to think of storing your items on a 5,000 limit per folder / view or what approach you use.

I would like to ask, what if there is a possibility to NOT be able to group the items in some way? For example, the only column used is an ID (WIN-xx) where xx is an incrementing number. There are no categories available to be able to sort them into folders or views. I can probably group them to show only the 5,000 recent items, but how then can I show the items that exceed the 5,000 item limit? For example, I want to reference the "old" items.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There will not be a problem in this case if their is only one column that is ID(OOB column).
This column is always indexed. Hence, if you query with index column, it will give results with no problem.

However if you add a column which is not indexed, then your question is valid. It will create a problem in that case you need to index that column, or you can retrieve the data using Object model.

You can have detail [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15493/sharepoint-2010-column-index-on-large-list)

Comment: Thanks Varun! But won't I still be limited to returning only 5,000 items on a List View? Above that, it's going to lock up the SQL database?

I read through the link you provided though that seems to be more geared towards sorting issues?

Comment: You want to return more than 5000 items from your query. if this is the question you can always override the QueryThrottleMode property of the SPQuery object to ignore the list view threshold as follows                      SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
 
oQuery.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;

Comment: And lock up SQL? NO. if you will design your list earlier than populating >5000 items it will not. Lock occurs if you have >5000 items and then you are indexing !

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I read that it will lock up SQL. So I guess it really depends on how to design the lists.

Answer (score 0):

When a list or library has a large number of items, you must carefully plan its organization and how users need to access the data. By planning and using a few key list and library features, you can ensure that users can find information without adversely affecting the performance of the rest of your site.

Ways to manage large lists and libraries
Index a column
Create a filtered view by using an indexed column
Add an indexed column to an existing view
Set limits for RSS Feeds

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010173667.aspx

You can increase the threshold limit if you want to:

```
1- Login to Central Admin
2- Go to Application Management -> Manage Web Applications
3- Pick the Web application for which you want to change the LVT (If you only have 1 web app plus the central admin one, the one you want to pick is the 1 web app; changing this for the central admin does you no good)
4- In the ribbon above, click General Settings. That will bring down a menu, from which you should pick Resource Throttling
5- Change the LVT (first item in this list) to another value and press OK, but please try to keep it to a reasonable number!
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold.aspx

Let me know if you have any other concerns.